# In what cases javaw.exe still remain in memory after system.exit(0).?

Tags: java

I have code which is exiting using `System.exit(0)`  but `javaw.exe` is still running in task manager .There is no exception in Code block and we are reaching the line of Code for `System.exit(0)`.

Can any body tell  under what conditions it  may fail to  kill `javaw.exe` process

Comment: "... System.exit(0) and all the **t** but ..." ?

Comment: Why are you so sure about reaching the exit? Could you share your code?

Comment: A thread might be still alive in your app, therefore not reaching the exit. Use the console to debug your code, stop using javaw. Use javavm (included in the sdk) in order to assess any possible leak/deathlock/whateverisgoingwrong in your app.

Comment: Are there any shutdown hooks in your application? Seems as if you should monitor the process, see what's going on

Comment: @ra2085-Issue is not reproducible on  my machine ,its on client machine, so I am not sure what to  check and where to check

Comment: @VinceEmigh: Shut down hooks are used , but not for our application , but for third part application .What do we need to do with the Shut down hooks

Answer (score 0):

Normally there should be no more javaw.exe. Amything else indicates that the java application is not completely terminated.

Note that System.exit causes all registered shutdown hooks to be executed. You may use Runtime.halt (which omits execution of shutdown hooks) to check whether a shutdown hook is a problem.

If there is no problem with any shutdown there should be some thread. Maybe use Java Mission Control or something similar to dig deeper into this. You could also enforce Java to write thread dumps.

In the rare case of you having exploited JDK bugs you will find some files with a name similar to hs_error (probably in your home / user profile directory).